# Get rails route helper from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to automate the creation of breadcrumbs for the backend of my rails app. Im almost there I just need to be able to do one thing to finish it off.

I need to be able to get the route helper for the current request url.

So for example:

the current url is `/admin/pages`

So i need a way of getting the helper for that url which would be `admin_pages_path`

I want something like `get_path_from_url(request.original_url) # returns admin_pages_path helper`

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this. Path helpers go one way, from method to URL. You can't go from URL to method. For one thing, there can be multiple path-helper methods that return `/admin/pages`.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you what strange ways you chose to get something done. If you really want to do such things you can check the pattern in url and conditionally decide the helper method

it will be somewhat like

```
url_path_map = {
    /admin\/pages/ => :admin_pages_path_helper,
    /admin\/pages\/\d/ => :admin_page_path_helper
}

incoming_url = '/admin/pages'
helper = url_path_map.select{|url_rgex, helper| incoming_url.match(url_rgex).present?}.first[1]
```

finally call helper like

```
send helper
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, ill give this a go when i get home. The reason Im doing it is because Im using this gem https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails and I want to automate the breadcrumbs based on the current route and the gem requires you pass it the route helper to generate the link. Thanks again, ill let you know if it works and accept.